# VLC Player shows DVD menu correctly but absolutely butchers the movie

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, dvd

I wanted to rewatch the Avatar Aang series and went through the first DVD with no problems. The second DVD however is unwatchable. While the dvd itself shows no damage on the outside, this is what it looks like when I click on "play" in the DVD menu (while the menu itself is displayed fine):
I don't even know what to google for, as I have no idea what this effect is called.

Win7 64bit
Intel i7-2640M @2.8 GHz
8GB Ram
intel hd graphics 3000

[image: DVD Menu]

[image: DVD Play]

Comment: It's a key-framing issue - basically the player can't keep up. Quick tests; reboot puter, run only VLC, nothing else; try another player.

Comment: As a suggestion, try Media Player Classic from https://mpc-hc.org  Not guaranteed, but it's often proven to be a good alternative for me when VLC can't hack it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

MPEG2 which is used on DVD's has this issue.

- Either you cannot read the DVD fast enough to display the "full"-pictures in time and thus only display the "difference"-pictures (try copying the DVD contents (*TS-directories) to your computer and play it again).
- Or the encoding of the DVD is in some way not compatible with your decoder (try changing the decoder in the settings).
- Or all your "full"-pictures are magically broken (try encoding it to h.264 (e.g. with handbrake) and see what happens).
- Or your DVD is broken.